# Getting unexpected row counts in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am executing following two queries on MySQL database using JDBC connection in JAVA.

1:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM transaction 
WHERE 
    (entry_time between STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-24 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s') 
    AND STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-24 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s'))
```

2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM transaction 
WHERE 
    (entry_time between STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-24 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s') 
    AND STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-24 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s'))
```

When I am searching continuously I am getting different records each time.
for e.g.

1. 68
2. 72
3. 58
4. 69

I printed the output in a log file and found that for 1st query it brings the value which is in actual in database. When the second query is executed and there is some process going on it gives different values. Why is it so?

My second question is for the second query I am getting values for '2012-09-23' also. But as per the range specified it should not bring it.

I am using MySQL 5.1 and JAVA 1.6.0_14. This is a Web Application which is now on a production server. Where I cannot debug it. :( the problem is occurring only on the production server the test setup works fine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you pass the dates? do you use literals or do you bind variables?

Comment: Use literals. I create the SQL statement in a string and then use that string to create a query object which is then executed.

Comment: Try %H in place of %k for hours conversion. I don't think that's your problem, but it might be.  (%k = hours 0-24, %H = hours 00-24).  Also: notice that your query is asking about transactions on the day you posted this question.  Is it possible your production server is actively inserting or deleting rows from the transaction table?

Comment: Yes the production server is actively inserting the records in the transaction table when we are querying it. But when a row is inserted in a table only that row would be locked not the entire table. Right?

Comment: Does it ever delete records? That will cause the number of results to go down. For your second question about times on the wrong day, it sounds like a timezone problem.

Comment: `@Barmer` the application does not delete any records from the transaction table. The time stored in the database is in UTC which is then converted into user specified timezone.